# What key combinations are really convenient and not reserved by most programs (i.e., suitable for binds)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I don't like 3-key combinations; two is the max. I've tried using numpad but my hand is almost never on that side of the KB, so I think I'll shift to the left side.

I know that I don't want to override things like Ctrl-F. I'm thinking about using the numbers above QWERTY, and then have some kind of flag that I can set with tilde or scroll lock; when the flag is off I can use the numbers for number input.

I'm sure other people have thought about many more creative ideas.

Comment: What Os/Distro are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 10char

Comment: Before you settle on something, be sure to try it out on several different keyboards.  The way keyboards work, some "chords" work better than others, and it varies with the specific layout of the internal KB wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a separate USB-numkeypad and use HID-Macros* (a French program that allows you to differentiate between KB's and can work together with ahk) to create your Hotkeys there.

Also consider HotStrings.

You could remap the CapsLock function to LShift & RShift combined and "re-use" the capslock as another modifier key like this:

```
#If GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")
    a::SoundBeep, 500, 500
    s::SoundBeep, 500, 100
#If
```

P.s. this requires ahk_L.

- HIDMacros does have some issues with "international" keyboard settings, where the "dead" keys like ~"^ etc to create ü or é don't work, but using ahk, you can solve that as well.